# Add the characters of word into the JButtons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

How can I add the characters of word in to the JButtons?

I am using a **For loop** to draw the JButtons on the Panel. Numbers of the JButtons depend on the length of the word. I am using an **Array** to add words in the there.

**An array of words**

```
String words[] = {"JAVA" , "FLOAT" , "VOID", "MAIN" , "STATIC", "FINAL", "PRIVATE" , "CHAR" , "ÏF" , "ELSE", "WHILE" ,
                   "DO" , "BOOLEAN" , "TRY" , "CATCH" , "SWITCH" , "CASE" , "STRING" , "INT" , "DOUBLE"};
```

**This is the string which chooses the random word from the Array of words**

```
String word = words[myRandom.nextInt(words.length)];
```

**This is the For loop to draw the JButtons. As I mentioned above, number of JButtons depend on the length of the WORD**

```
for(int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++)
                {
                    Buttons[i] = new JButton();
                    Buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));

                    gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
                    gridConstraints.gridy = 0;

                    second.add(Buttons[i]);
                    second.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));

                }
```

So now my problem is, I want to show that word on the JButtons

For example: Word is **DO** , So, this will allow the **For loop** to draw the Two JButtons, Now I want, One Jbutton will show the word "D" & the other JButton will show the word "O".

Comment: `Buttons[i].setText(word.charAt(i))`? And the loop indexing is incorrect, it should be `[0, word.length)`

Comment: `setPreferredSize(`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact sizing or placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @vidit: I changed the index, but the method you suggested " Buttons[i].setText(word.charAt(i))" is not working. It is giving me an error.....

Comment: @CrazyPixi- What error?

Comment: @vidit: The error is " java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4 "

Comment: @CrazyPixi- How does the declaration of `Buttons` look like?

Comment: What line is the error being reported to? I feel like your `for-loop` shouldn't compile. You start your loop at `i=1` and then assign `buttons` to an index value of `1` when arrays begin at `0`.

Comment: Vidit: JButton Buttons[] = new JButton[10]; , This is declared in the class

Comment: @Tdorno: After adding that line "Buttons[i].setText(word.charAt(i) + ""); " , Its give me an error, as above I mentioned.

Comment: @CrazyPixi before you took my earlier recommendation was the error referencing the same line?

Comment: I changed as you mentioned about the index, but it still doesn't work @Tdorno

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as the in the comments mentioned, you need to set charAt(i) for every JButton. As I checked, your value of **i** is right. while the charAt(i) is starting from zero. So, as you have the value of i = 1, you just need to subtract 1 from there(i-1), this will work for sure....    :)

```
                   for(int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++)
                {

                    Buttons[i] = new JButton();
                    Buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));

                    Buttons[i].setText(word.charAt(i-1) + ""); 
                    second.add(Buttons[i]);
                    second.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));

                }
```